# What is wrong with my code in my java yahtzee game?

Tags: java

I am writing code for a yahtzee game in java and I need to write a method which allows the user to choose which dice to keep and which dice to re-roll. The part I'm having trouble with is that the user must be able to choose more than one value to keep.

For example on the first roll they may choose to keep `3`'s, `5`'s, and a `6`. This is what I have so far, but the correct dice are not being kept when I test it.

```
//keep method
public void keep(int[] keepThis) {
    for(int i = 0; i < keepOrRollArray.length; i++) {   
        for(int p = 0; p < keepThis.length; p++) {
            if(faceValueArray[i] == keepThis[p])
                keepOrRollArray[p] = 'K';
        }
    }
}
```

//keep method tested after a roll

```
newDiceArray.roll();
int[] userValue = new int[2];
userValue[0] = 3;
userValue[1] = 4;
newDiceArray.keep(userValue);
System.out.println("Practice roll: " + "\n" + newDiceArray +"\n");
```

Comment: please post rest of code along with the output you are getting and the output you want

Answer (score -2):

First off, I'm guessing that there is quite a bit more to your code than what you have posted.  (Otherwise, your code is egregiously incomplete, not to put too fine of a point on it).  Without this additional code, we can't really help much.

In the meantime, however, if what you have isn't "keeping" the correct dice, you might ought to try having five separate questions querying the user whether they want to keep each of the dice: "Do you want to keep dice #1", "Do you want to keep dice #2" etc.  Then update your `keepThis` array appropriately.